# Prove the limit of a negligible function times a simple polynomial

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following definition of a negligible function:
A **function $f: \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is negligible** if for all $c \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, there exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ such that for all integers $n \geq n_0$, we have $|f(n)| < \frac{1}{n^c}$.

And I am given the **following question**: prove that, if $f$ is negligible, then for all $c > 0$, we have: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(n)n^c = 0$.

My current solution is similar to the following: rewrite $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(n)}{1/n^c}$. As $n \rightarrow \infty$, the denominator approaches zero and so does the numerator, but since $f$ is negligible, the numerator is always smaller than the denominator. So the limit is 0.

Is this correct? If not, how to solve it?

Comment: This is not quite correct.  It's not enough to say that the numerator is always smaller than the denominator.  For instance, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{2n}$ is not equal to $0$ even though the numerator is always smaller than the denominator.  You are missing a key step that is exploited in stowo's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is intuitively correct, although not quite formal. Here is a quick formalization of your proof.

Fix an arbitrary real number $c > 0$. Since $f$ is negligible, there exists some integer $n_0 \ge 1$ such that $|f(n)| < 1/(n^{c+1})$ for all integers $n \ge n_0$. Hence, we have for all integers $n \ge n_0$ that
$$
|f(n)n^c| = n^c|f(n)| < n^c\frac{1}{n^{c+1}} = \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Since $1/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, we conclude (by the squeeze theorem or classical epsilon-delta arguments, try this yourself if you wish) that $|f(n)n^c| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. In other words, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)n^c = 0$.

edit: fixed typo